Export all descriptions to text file or Excel
In my Anylogic model I described all model parts in the corresponding description field. I now want to export all these descriptions to a text or Excel file. The descriptions shoul be exported with the Name of its model part.

I know that there is a Create Documentation function but I only want to export the name and description of each part without any other information.
Many thanks for your help in advance.
Best regards

No pre-build way. However, you can write some code (maybe ChatGPT can help) to export the text from the raw .alp model file.
Open your model .alp file with a text editor and you can see it is all (xml) text. Search for <description> tab to find your descriptions.
Or do that from the created documentation itself
